# Custom operator new() without modifying the class

Tags: c++, new-operator

For an embedded system I'd like to be able to override the new()-operator of an existing class, without modifying the class' source code (same applies for delete() of course).

The background: the class (let's call it Foo) is used on a platform with a MMU (so the standard new-operator is OK) as well as on a limited platform without MMU, requiring some kind of memory pool to prevent memory fragmentation.

Unfortunately, the following won't work, as Foo doesn't declare a custom new operator:

Foo.hpp:

```
class Foo
{
  .. // no declaration for new() operator!
}
```

main.c:

```
...
void* Foo::operator new(std::size_t sz) { ... }
...
```

However, if Foo::new *is* declared in Foo.hpp without providing an implementation, the user of the class is forced to provide the implementation, even if std::new would be perfectly suitable. I'd like to avoid that, respecting usability.

Deriving a specialized version of Foo isn't a solution, too, as Foo will be instantiated by a factory class, that isn't (an shall not be) aware of the derivate.

The only way I found is declaring Foo::new encapsulated within a #define, if the user needs to provide a custom one, e.g.:

```
class Foo
{
#ifdef FOO_USE_CUSTOM_NEW
  void* operator new(std::size_t sz) { ... }
#endif
}
```

Well, that's looking more like C than C++...

There must be a better way to realise this purpose. Last but not least, the compiler unfortunately is limited to C++98.

Comment: If `Foo` is created by a factory, why not make the factory allocator-aware?

Comment: I'd guess that you'd need some context on where the object needs to be allocated anyway. Using an allocator is providing the necessary context. On the implementation where the location doesn't matter the alloator could just use the system's `operator new()`/`operator delete()`. On an embedded system the allocator would refer to the memory pool. Effectively, using an allocator is a fancy way to placement new.

Comment: @krzaq: The factory would have to be aware of any derivate, I'd like to avoid this.

Comment: @Dietmar: this sounds very interesting to me! I heard of allocators, and due to your suggestion were able to find some tutorials concerning how to design an allocator, but only in conjunction with STL containers. But I have no further previous knowlege about this concept. Can you give an example of how to _use_ an allocator? Does `new Foo()` use the allocator automatically?

Comment: @SirFrancisDrake: The short version is something like `T* p new(allocator) T(args...);`. It requires a suitable type and `operator new()` overload. It also requirers, unfortunately, manual destruction and release: `p->~T(); allocator.deallocate(p);`. Since contained objects should. use the allocator, too, it is generally needed to propagate the allocator to members possibly needing allocations. ... and, no, the default `operator new()` doesn't use an allocator. It can be replaced, however.

Comment: This means, the factory class needs to be passed the allocator (now I understand krzaq's suggestion), which is used any time when instantiating Foo? OK, but this potentially would affect many parts of our existing software assets, and could be error prone, if someone still uses new() nevertheless, instead of using the allocator (well, maybe `new` could be set private, with a friend relation to the allocator).